# Failed to install a node-red pallete?

Tags: ibm-watson, node-red, watson-assistant

I am attempting to create a chatbot on Facebook using Watson Conversation and linking it via Node-Red. I have been following a tutorial which requires me to install a node-red-contrib-facebook-messenger-writer palette, but unfortunately, I am confronted with this error msg.

*Failed to install: node-red-contrib-facebook-messenger-writer*

*Install failed*

I have only tried re-installing it, but with no luck.

---

Additionally, this is the error msg expanded

```
2020-01-21T14:24:33.490Z Install : node-red-contrib-facebook-messenger-writer 0.0.4

2020-01-21T14:24:33.885Z npm install --no-audit --no-update-notifier --save --save-prefix="~" --production node-red-contrib-facebook-messenger-writer@0.0.4
2020-01-21T14:24:36.994Z [err] npm
2020-01-21T14:24:36.994Z [err]  
2020-01-21T14:24:36.994Z [err] WARN
2020-01-21T14:24:36.994Z [err]  
2020-01-21T14:24:36.994Z [err] deprecated
2020-01-21T14:24:36.994Z [err]  hawk@6.0.2: This module moved to @hapi/hawk. Please make sure to switch over as this distribution is no longer supported and may contain bugs and critical security issues.
2020-01-21T14:24:38.090Z [err] npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
2020-01-21T14:24:38.097Z [err] npm
2020-01-21T14:24:38.097Z [err]  WARN deprecated sntp@2.1.0: This module moved to @hapi/sntp. Please make sure to switch over as this distribution is no longer supported and may contain bugs and critical security issues.
2020-01-21T14:24:38.103Z [err] npm
2020-01-21T14:24:38.103Z [err]  WARN deprecated boom@4.3.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
2020-01-21T14:24:38.210Z [err] npm
2020-01-21T14:24:38.210Z [err]  WARN deprecated cryptiles@3.1.4: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
2020-01-21T14:24:38.222Z [err] npm WARN deprecated boom@5.2.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
2020-01-21T14:25:41.283Z rc=null
```

Could someone enlighten me on the error at hand?

Answer (score 0):

The only dependancy that `node-red-contrib-facebook-messenger-writer` is on `request` (currently 2.86.0). The packages that you list are dependancies of dependancies.

Bumping the dependancy to 2.88.0, sorted out the vulnerabilities in the nested dependancies. I have just published a published a new version of the node - 0.0.5.